# Developer Story - "Joined Stack Overflow" Missing

Tags: support, developer-story

Most Developer Story pages I see have a "Joined Stack Overflow" milestone in their timeline, but I never got one on mine.

Is there a reason why not everyone would have this milestone on their timeline automatically, seeing as we all have join dates? I'd like to add one, as the automatic milestone looks fancier than a generic "milestone", but can't figure out how.

Comment: I don't have it on mine either, and I don't seem to be able to add it. Do you have a link to a Story that has this?

Comment: [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/4909087) has it

Comment: Confirm, I am missing it too. It seems we do not comply to some criteria :)

Comment: I'm not seeing it on my Developer Story.  (But maybe I deleted it at some stage in the past?  If so, I would still expect some way to say I changed my mind and want to add it back in.)

Comment: Just want to say I do have it, and I have the option of deleting it: [image](https://i.imgur.com/xYtpejJ.png)

Comment: I can confirm I don't have it too, even though i joined one month, which is April 2015, before coldspeed (the profile linked by @Wndrr), who joined in May 2015.

Comment: Probably something to do with number of items, i.e. if theres not many pad with "Joined Stack Overflow"

Comment: @AshleyMedway I only have one item in my story (I don't use it) and don't see the "Joined Stack Overflow" milestone so that can't be the reason.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I also only have a couple items and don't have the ability to add it, nor have I ever seen it. Weird that chade_ also never got the option, meaning it's not a feature they removed over time...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This auto-generated story item was shipped in Feb. 2017 and is granted to users as part of the developer story onboarding/creation process. Therefore users who created a developer story before Feb. 2017 do not have this milestone. We did not backfill this to all users with an existing developer story because we did not want to modify your story without you knowing, especially since you may haven chosen to share it with employers. For now, I have manually added it to your story.

Comment: Ah this makes sense - thanks!

Comment: So whats the solution for everyone that wants to add this to their profile?

Comment: +1 for not adding it without informing. I don't use the developer story, but it's still important that I'm informed

Comment: @AshleyMedway we punted on that for now, but I can manually grant you one if you'd like.

Comment: @js12 sure, I'm not going to turn down a freebie :)

Comment: I'd like to have that as well, thanks :) Maybe you should add it in a hidden state to all users, so that those who have already created their developer stories can enable it.

Comment: @jisoo could you add it to my developer story too?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ sure

Comment: @jisoo By any chance, would you mind adding this to my [story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/cassiomolin) too?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin done!

Comment: @jisoo same request from me. Thanks in advance!
https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2036886

Comment: @EvgeniyMalyutin added!

Comment: @jisoo could you add it to my developer story too? Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/5343866

Comment: @jisooshin could you add it to mine as well? Is it to late to ask for it XD? Thanks in advance! https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/7395911